# after updating form in django it create new instance of the form instead of updating it

Tags: python, django

i haven't been able to correct the code and it doesn't work just inserting the question in database after every update means multiple objects are returned. Here's the view code

```
views.py

#form for creating question
def get_name(request): 
    if request.method=='POST':
        form = QuestionForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('poll:index'))
    else:
        form = QuestionForm()
    return render(request,'poll/name.html',{'form':form})

#for updating the form
def update(request,question_id=None): 
    instance=get_object_or_404(Question,pk=question_id)
    if request.method=='POST':
        form = QuestionForm(request.POST,instance=instance)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance=form.save(commit=False)
            instance.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(instance.get_absolute_url())
    else:
        form=QuestionForm(instance=instance)
    return render(request,'poll/name.html',{'form':form})

#urls.py

app_name='poll'

urlpatterns=[
                path('',views.index,name='index'),
                path('create/',views.get_name,name='create'),
                path('<int:question_id>/',views.detail,name='detail'),
                path('int:question_id/update',views.update,name='update'),
             ]
```

Comment: check if this condition "if question_id:" is returning True.

Comment: Best if an update view cannot be invoked without a question_id (urls.py). Then just use `get_object_or_404` which guarantees you do have something to update if it does not 404.

Comment: Show us the place where your `update()` view gets invoked: Where is the url defined? And where is it constructed (in your template)? Also remove `=None` in the view definition, that'll ensure that you always pass a question to your view.